# connect laravel to another instance of MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have 2 instances of running MySQLs on different ports (3333 and 3306)

image from workbench

[image]

my laravel project is dealing with the one in port 3333
by using these codes

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3333
DB_DATABASE=bglee
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

I'd like now to make it deal with port 3306

I edited the above codes to

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=bglee
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

but now he still works with the first port (3333)

in case running `php artisan migrate` , it creates the tables in the first instance (3333)

unfortunately I want Laravel to deal with the second one (3306)

because it has updated version of MySQL

contents of config/database.php

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Database Connection Name
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify which of the database connections below you wish
    | to use as your default connection for all database work. Of course
    | you may use many connections at once using the Database library.
    |
    */

    'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Database Connections
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here are each of the database connections setup for your application.
    | Of course, examples of configuring each database platform that is
    | supported by Laravel is shown below to make development simple.
    |
    |
    | All database work in Laravel is done through the PHP PDO facilities
    | so make sure you have the driver for your particular database of
    | choice installed on your machine before you begin development.
    |
    */

    'connections' => [

        'sqlite' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlite',
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
            'prefix' => '',
        ],

        'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock', 
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
        ],

        'pgsql' => [
            'driver' => 'pgsql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'schema' => 'public',
            'sslmode' => 'prefer',
        ],

        'sqlsrv' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '1433'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
        ],

    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Migration Repository Table
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This table keeps track of all the migrations that have already run for
    | your application. Using this information, we can determine which of
    | the migrations on disk haven't actually been run in the database.
    |
    */

    'migrations' => 'migrations',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Redis Databases
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Redis is an open source, fast, and advanced key-value store that also
    | provides a richer set of commands than a typical key-value systems
    | such as APC or Memcached. Laravel makes it easy to dig right in.
    |
    */

    'redis' => [

        'client' => 'predis',

        'default' => [
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
            'database' => 0,
        ],

    ],

];
```

Comment: Can you post the contents of `config/database.php`?

Comment: @JoshRumbut - I think the new versions of Laravel always deal with .env file - anyway I updated the question , check it

Comment: Oh I think the socket you're specifying might be the issue here, I'm not sure how XAMPP handles that.

Answer (score 4):

There's some information about this on the Laravel documentation, as seen here for version 5.6:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/database#using-multiple-database-connections

So, in your `config/database.php` file, you'd create another connection that mirrors your original one, but with the correct port, maybe like this:

```
...
'connections' => [
    ...
        'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
        ],

        'mysql_2' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST_2', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT_2', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE_2', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME_2', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD_2', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET_2', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
        ],
    ...
],
```

Then, in your `.env` file, you can put the following values:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=bglee
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

DB_CONNECTION_2=mysql_2
DB_HOST_2=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT_2=3333
DB_DATABASE_2=bglee
DB_USERNAME_2=root
DB_PASSWORD_2=
```

And finally, you can migrate to a specific database using `php artisan migrate --database=mysql_2`.

Not sure if this is the BEST way to do it for your situation, but that's how I would try and approach it.

Comment: Great answer. Welcome to SO!

Comment: not works , Database [DB_CONNECTION_2] not configured also Database [DB_CONNECTION] not configured if I used "php artisan migrate --database=DB_CONNECTION_2"

Comment: @AboMohsen You'd do `php artisan migrate --database=mysql_2`.

Comment: oops, I had that migrate command at first, and then I corrected it. I'll re-correct it!

Comment: both "php artisan migrate --database=mysql_2" and "php artisan migrate --database=mysql" are dealing with port (3333) , so strange

Comment: if no possible to achieve this - anyway to upgrade mysql in port 3333

Comment: @AboMohsen, I'm no mysql expert, but would that be because you have the same DB_DATABASE value for both connections on the same server? I've never used this exact setup before.  edit: clarification